# KeyNotYetValidException when using Android Keystore

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

Currently I'm using Android Keystore in my app to obfuscate Shared Preferences, in order to store personal data from the user.

It currently happens right now that when trying to use Keystore with an specific device (Oneplus 3T, running Android 7.1.1), the Cipher crashes using the generated Key, with the error `KeyNotYetValidException`. In other devices it does not crash.

I tried setting the key validity start to the past year, but got the same issue.

Here's the Key creation code:

```
val start = GregorianCalendar()
start.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1)

val end = GregorianCalendar()
end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 25)

lateinit var spec: AlgorithmParameterSpec

spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(ALIAS, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT.or(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT))
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                .setCertificateSubject(X500Principal("CN=$ALIAS"))
                .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
                .setKeyValidityStart(start.time)
                .setKeyValidityEnd(end.time)
                .build()
```

And this is the stacktrace I get:

```
Caused by: android.security.keystore.KeyNotYetValidException: Key not yet valid
at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:684)
at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:748)
at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2977)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2884)
at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2789)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:956)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1199)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
at com.app.myapp.SecureStorage.booo006F006F006Foooo
```

Any recommendation here?

Comment: This link may help you   https://github.com/iamMehedi/Secured-Preference-Store/issues/15

Comment: yes @ramyabr I checked but modifying the startDate doesn't seem to solve the issue

Comment: What's the date/time on that specific device?